# Clarification on "password" argument for web3.eth.personal.sign

Tags: web3js, web3js-v1.x

Context: I'm fairly new to web3, and as we all know it's developing quite regularly. I'm working towards a "sign in with Metamask"-type functionality using `web3@1.0.0-beta.46`.

Most of the docs/discussions online I've seen recommend using `web3.eth.personal.sign` over the other signing methods (at least for the purpose of signing a message to prove ownership of an address), but all examples I've seen online seem to ignore the third argument, `password`, which is described in the docs as "The password of the account to sign data with."

Up until `1.0.0-beta.38`, the `password` argument could be left undefined, but with `38` now throws `Invalid Arguments length: expected: 3, given: 2`.

Looking at the docs, they provide an example:
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html#sign

```js
web3.eth.personal.sign("Hello world", "0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe", "test password!")
.then(console.log);
```

It seems silly to simply pass in a static string. There's gotta be something here I'm not getting.

Can someone clarify what the point of the password argument is? <s>Is it to be used like a challenge or a salt? Should I pass in my nonce, instead of adding it to the message string?</s>  Am I way off?

I'll keep digging, but could use some guidance. Thanks.

edit: changing the password value doesn't change the signature.

Comment: For anyone else with the same issue, the accepted answer in this post answers this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84763/sign-function-of-web3-js-for-authenticating-users-via-metamask

Answer (score 1):

it is the password that you pass when calling function to create new account

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html#newaccount

Comment: I've never created a new account. As a user, have a default account, and I might have imported accounts. But the application has never created a new account using web3. And it seems like I can sign a message for a user using their default account when passing any random string along to the "password" argument, which is why I'm confused...